# What are different types of dimmers?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I want to make a dimmer that would regulate the heating of an electric blanket using Arduino. I thought I'd use a Triac dimming circuit design for incandescent lights from the internet.

Are those the right type of dimmer to use with my electric blanket?

Here are some photos of the controller unit:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This thread is old, I know, but for the benefit of future readers, the yellow block is not a SSR; it's a capacitor. The whole circuit appears to be a positive phase angle power controller. Q1 is probably a triac. The neon bulb (little orange glowing light) is probably used instead of a diac (trigger and hold for the triac gate). A neon bulb behaves a lot like a diac and they are cheaper in the mass volumes a manufacturer of cheap electric blankets might produce. So, this looks nearly identical to a circuit that might be used for a light dimmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Without knowing specifics of the electric blanket, and what it contains as internal electronics, it is difficult to provide a definitive answer.*

The simplistic assumption I was tempted to make, that the electric blanket essentially has just a bunch of resistances (wires) as heating elements, is unsubstantiated:
That kind of design could be potentially fatal if one were to damage the blanket and touch mains-voltage heaters!

If one were to assume that whatever electronics the blanket integrates, is compatible with a varying partial sine wave mains supply, then yes, a triac dimmer of sufficient power rating would be the way to go.

If not, a simple alternative would be to implement a dimmer consisting of a suitably rated **solid-state relay controlled by some timer circuit**, to switch the blanket on and off every few minutes, with the on-time percentage varying according to desired temperature.

The reason this would work is:
An electric blanket (under typical use cases) does not need its temperature precisely controlled on a continuous basis. The heating itself takes many minutes, so a power cycling span of minutes would be acceptable to even out the temperature to a desired set-point.

The **SSR** is suggested instead of a conventional electromagnetic relay, because it would operate silently, and also would last longer due to not having parts prone to mechanical wear or contact arcing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't know a whole lot about the blanket either. I just know that its temperature is currently controlled using a manual potentiometer. Also it functions under two modes that determines the twi different running time. What other information would be helpful to know about?

Comment: @Am01 That information should be sufficient if using the on-off timed switching solution proposed in this answer.

Comment: I added some photos for you to look at. Do you have any suggestion for the SSR component?

Comment: Dumb question coming your way. You said ` the potentiometer is being used to with a timer to set the on-off times of the relay`. I think the potentiometer only controls the temperature and the big black switch above the relay controls the timer. Am I missing something? What can I replace the potentiameter with so the temperature can be controlled via Arduino? are you suggesting to manually turn the heater on and off to replicate what the potentiometer does currently while the heater is on?

Comment: @Am01 Not a dumb question. The big black switch may control whether the timer is in operation at all (or maybe whether the heating itself is in operation), but when you say "controls the temperature", the way such a device would control the temperature would be to use a cyclic timer to turn on and off the heating coils every so many minutes. If it's on a minute and off for 5, that'll achieve one temperature, 1 minute on 1 minute off will achieve a much warmer temperature, and so on. The adjusting of the potentiometer sets this timing cycle, thus indirectly adjusting the desired temperature.

Comment: You are a genius :) Thanks for putting up with my ignorance.

Comment: What do you think about this SSR? Will it do the job? http://bit.ly/113OHFV

Comment: @Am01 Specific shopping questions are frowned upon here, but you are on the right track; Look for an SSR module that is rated for higher than the maximum current your blanket can draw (double is good), and for a contact voltage higher than your power line voltage. You do not need a 2-channel SSR module, but those seem to be cheaper than single channel ones (!) in AU.

Comment: I need two channel so I can separate the two sides of the blanket. Thanks for that answer.